# Project Euler #168 in Ruby; Has anyone gotten an answer?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, range, iteration

[Project Euler problem #168](https://projecteuler.net/problem=168). My solution is:

```
num = (10..10**10).inject(0) do |sum,x| 
x.to_s.chars.rotate(-1).join.to_i % x == 0 ? sum += x : sum += 0
end
puts num.to_s[-5..-1].to_i
```

The problem I'm dealing with is that I don't know is if this 'solution' is right or wrong. When I try to run in on the terminal I don't get error messages or an answer. It just looks as if the answer is loading, but no answer appears.

I would assume that's because the array is so large, so how could I find the answer another way? I know there aren't bugs with the code because I tried a smaller range, like 10..10**6 and it worked.

Comment: This cannot be solved with brute-force.10^100 is too big a number. Like most Project Euler questions there is some 'clever mathematical property' that must be exploited.

Comment: So is there any other way to figure out the problem? I just want to know the answer lol

Comment: @JorgeLopezJr: I suggest that you Google around on the web for explanations. Project Euler is meant to be a challenge, and you should put in your share of the effort - whether it's on solving the problem or researching what's known. The Stack Overflow community might give you an answer in easy/lucky cases, but this is not a guarantee.

Comment: @JorgeLopezJr, Fortunately there are much less than 10**100 numbers you'll need to look at. Figure out the patterns of digits that can satisfy the constraint.

Comment: Whole point of this challange is that this array is too large to iterate over each element.

Answer (score 2):

The number has this right-rotation property has the form:

```
ABCD and DABC = k*ABCD
```

We can easily see that, `k` should be less than 10, because, if `k` larger than 10, `k*ABCD` will have more digits than `ABCD`.

For each number of `k` from `1` to `9`, and with most significant digit (MSD) is `a`, `a from k to 9`, we can find the minimum number `X` that satisfy `X / k` is the left rotation of `X`, and `X` has its MSD is `a`.

Pseudo-code:

```
for(int k = 1; k < 10; k++){
   for(int a = k ; a < 10; a++){
       long X = 0;
       int cur = a;
       int mod = 0;
       do{
          X = X*10 + cur;
          cur = (mod*10 + cur)/k; //Result of this division is the next digit of X
          mod = (mod*10 + cur)%k; 
          if(pair <cur, mod> seen before)
             break;         
       }while(cur != a && mod != 0);
       //Notice that we will iterate less than 100 steps, as there is only 10*10 value of pair (cur, mod).
   }
}
```

We notice that, all number Y  < 10 ^ 100 which `Y / k` is the left rotation of `Y` will have the form `XXXXXX...`

So, the job is now simple, as each `Y` will end with `X`, just keep the last 5 digit of `X` and multiply with the amount of valid `Y` numbers ( = 100 / number of digits of X).

Sum all those 5 digits, we will get the answer for this problem.